# How to delete pagination and search box in datatable

Tags: grails

I want to delete pagination, search box, etc from datatable, i tried lot to delete it but no result has came can anyone suggest me a solution for this

And i want to delete this pagination from list page alone so i placed following script in `list.gsp` but still its not working

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#gow').dataTable( {
            "bPaginate": false,
            "bFilter": false,
            "bInfo": false
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post how your list page looks like?

Comment: Thank you, i got it, its working now, i just replaced my previous script with                                                                                                <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#gow').dataTable({
 "bJQueryUI": true,
 "bPaginate": false,
 "bFilter": false,
 "bInfo": false,
 "aoColumnDefs" : [ {
      "bSortable" : false,
      "aTargets" : [ "no-sort" ]
  },{ sWidth: '20px', aTargets: [ '_all' ] }]
});
});
 </script>